# Combine Two Queries into One?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have a MySQL query that selects all `audioids` from a certain user in a `subscribe` table.

I then have another query which takes this list of `audioids` and matches them against a field called `opids` in a table called `audioposts`. It then selects the `titles` from that `audioposts` table and joins the users from a `users` table at the `userid`.

Is there a way I can turn these two queries into one query?

```
query1 = "SELECT audioid FROM subscribe WHERE userid = $userid";                            
                    
query2 = "SELECT ap.audioid, ap.title, us.name FROM audioposts ap                   
        INNER JOIN audioposts a2 ON a2.audioid = ap.opid
        INNER JOIN users us ON us.id = a2.userid 
        WHERE ap.opid = $newaudio";
```

Here is the current two query code which I'd like to replace with one query. I've not yet translated this into prepared statements as it's easier for me to visualize it the old-fashioned way. Plus I'll be converting this into NodejS eventually anyway;

```
    $selectaudioid = "SELECT audioid FROM subscribe WHERE userid = $userid";
    $audioResult=$dblink->query($selectaudioid);
    
        if ($audioResult->num_rows>0)   {       
            while ($row = $audioResult->fetch_assoc())  {
                $newaudio = $row[audioid];  
                $getallaudio = "                
                SELECT ap.audioid, ap.title, us.name FROM audioposts ap                     
                INNER JOIN audioposts a2 ON a2.audioid = ap.opid
                INNER JOIN users us ON us.id = a2.userid 
                WHERE ap.opid = $newaudio AND ap.opid <> '0'";
                
                $getallresult = $dblink->query($getallaudio);           
                
                if ($getallresult->num_rows>0)  {                       
                while ($row = $getallresult->fetch_assoc())  {
                    $dbdata[]=$row;                         
        }}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another join with `subscribe`.

```
SELECT ap.audioid, ap.title, us.name 
FROM audioposts ap                   
INNER JOIN audioposts a2 ON a2.audioid = ap.opid
INNER JOIN subscribe s ON s.audioid = ap.opid
INNER JOIN users us ON us.id = a2.userid 
WHERE s.userid = $userid AND ap.opid <> '0'
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound/executed queries

Comment: Unfortunately Barmar that produced 2 results but I needed 3 results.

Comment: That was real close. Heres what worked: SELECT ap.audioid, ap.title, us.name FROM audioposts ap                   
 INNER JOIN audioposts a2 ON a2.audioid = ap.opid
 INNER JOIN subscribe s ON s.audioid = ap.opid
 INNER JOIN users us ON us.id = a2.userid 
 WHERE $userid = ?  (it turned out I didn't really need AND ap.opid <> '0')

Comment: As you were really close if you edit in the correct  s.audioid = ap.opid, I'll select it as the asnwer.